# Excel - Multiple Line cells

Tags: excel

### Excel Multiple Lines

In excel i have cells with multiple lines in them - like this

```
25 Eagle Street
Boondall
```

What i am trying to do is make them back into one line again as follows -

```
25 Eagle Street Boondall
```

Is there some sort of way i can do this in excel? I have over 40000 cells to sort that are multiple lines. I am using a c# i created to separate the suburbs from the addresses, but i cannot do this with these multiple lines because i will get incorrect results. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If these are line breaks entered by pressing Alt+Enter, you can replace them all with Excel's find/replace command.  Select "Edit > Replace..." form the main menu or press the shortcut Ctrl+H and in the "Find what:" box you can enter the line-break code, which is character 10.  To do this, press and hold the Alt key, and then enter the numbers 010 from the numeric keypad.  You'll probably want to replace them with a space to maintain formatting.

Comment: Thank you! Worked for me :)